# Detox issue on React Native Expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, detox, react-native-ui-kitten

When I try to run my E2E test using Detox on my expo project, I got an unknown issue.
I have a **Input** component (@ui-ketten/component) and it's *testId* is *SignUpEmailInput*. I can navigate to the Signup screen in which the **Input** will be shown and I can see the **Input** component.
If I added this code to my app.e2e.js *await expect(element(by.id('SignUpEmailInput'))).toExist();*, then I can pass the test.
But if I add this code *await expect(element(by.id('SignUpEmailInput'))).toBeVisible();*, I can not pass the test.
Then I tested with --loglevel trace. I will share my error using screenshot

Comment: I've dealt with similar issues in the past. I suggest taking a screenshot with detox to check the app state.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a simulator before launching the Detox test suit. This way, the already open will be used to display the state.